# A mixed model with gamma distribution: handling zeros

Tags: mixed-model, gamma-distribution

I have a panel cost data with some zero values (not missing values but rounded to 0). How should I handle zeros when I use SAS Proc Glimmix with Gamma distribution? Maybe change zero to very small values? Or is there an option for it (which I couldn't find) in PROC GLIMMIX?

Janne

Comment: who did the rounding? Do you have access to the unrounded values?

Comment: No I don't. The data is collected as rounded: 0,1,2,3,...,100 even if the actual interval is 0-100.

Comment: it is not clear what panel cost data is, is it a proportion, or does the max just happen to be 100?

Answer (score 7):

I think you should consider a Poisson model instead. There was discussion of when it works and when it does not as an approximation to a continuous model on [Stata blog](http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/). If the values are restricted to a range from 0 to 100, you can also do binomial regression with it.

Answer (score 4):

If the zeros are a very small proportion of the data, I'd just move them to a small positive value (perhaps half the smallest positive observation).

If the number of zeros is approaching 10% of the data, I'd want to do something more complicated, like treat the outcome as a mixture of a gamma and a point mass at 0.

Comment: I don't know if thats possible in SAS: A gamma mixed model for values greater than zero (because of panel data; normally using Proc GLIMMIX) + proportion of zeros?

Comment: Why doesn't gamma work with 0s? The likelihood is defined at 0 for this distribution (it reduces to that of exponential distribution in this case).

Comment: The gamma distribution must be positive definite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution